# Unity Desktop black instead of unlock screen

Tags: unity, lenovo

I'm using a Lenovo Y510P with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I lock my computer or close it, instead of being able to unlock it I am given a black screen with the cursor. I have updated and upgraded to no avail. What can I do to fix this, or at least troubleshoot it?

Comment: Read `man pm-action` it will get you started on learning about "Power Management". There are scripts in `/etc/pm/config.d`, /etc/pm/sleep.d`, `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d` that are run when you suspend/resume. One of them is "helping" your display.

Comment: My display is coming back on, as I can see and move the cursor. Reading through `man pm-action` seemed to suggest it wouldn't receive power at all if that was the issue, but I may be wrong.